# Add multiple files using IDE or task runner

Tags: npm, webpack, gulp, webstorm

Working with component in angular is great, but each time we have to create a component we have to add multiple files:

1. js/ts
2. less/sass/scss...
3. html
4. ...

I wonder if it's possible to define somewhere (IDE or gulp, webpack ...) the set of files to create according to a unique user input?

ex: I would like to create a user component.
I will have to enter only one time user and it will create: user.js, user.css, user.html...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently possible using WebStorm; please vote for [IDEA-141225](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-141225) to be notified on any progress with this feature.

I'd suggest using existing node modules for generating components; for example, you can use [angular-1.5-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-1.5-cli) package to create AngularJS components. Cli can be integrated with WebStorm as an [external tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2018.3/settings-tools-external-tools.html)